# All In One Directive+Service+Controller

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering whether it is possible to build an independent directive.

I am very new on AngularJS, please, let me know if there are deep conceptual mistakes in what I am looking for.

My current "try" is:

```
(function () {
    // a module for holding the directive
    var app = angular.module('monitorApp', []);

    // a service for getting some data
    app.service("MonitorService", function ($http, $q) {
        return ({
            getMonitorInfo: getMonitorInfo
        });

        function GetMonitorInfo() {
            var request = $http({
                method: "get",
                url: "/IndicatorsReport/GetMonitorInfo"
            });
            return (request.then(notifyErrorIfNeed, handleError));
        }

        function handleError(response) {
            if (!angular.isObject(response.data) || !response.data.message) {
                return ($q.reject("An unknown error occurred."));
            }
            return ($q.reject(response.data.message));
        }

        function notifyErrorIfNeed(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            if (data.status !== "success") {
                new PNotify({
                    title: data.title,
                    text: data.text,
                    type: 'error',
                    hide: false,
                    styling: 'bootstrap3'
                });
            }
            return data;
        }
    });
```

// my actual directive

```
    app.directive('monitorButton', function ($document) {
        // a self initializing controller
        var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope, MonitorService) {
            var vm = this;
            function init() {
                MonitorService.GetMonitorInfo().then(function (data) {
                    // this is the actual data
                    vm.feedBots = data.feedBots;

                    // this is fake data yet
                    vm.flags = {
                        cls: 'bg-blue',
                        number: 3,
                        show: true
                    };
                });
            }
            init();
        }];

        //a very simple template
        var template = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-app">' +
                       '    <span class="badge {{vm.flags.cls}}" ng-show="vm.flags.show">{{vm.flags.number}}</span>'+
                       '    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Monitor'+
                       '</button>';

        // my directive params
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            controller: controller,
            scope: {},
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true,
            template: template
        };
    });
}());
```

I was intending to just add the following code to my html page (along with angularjs off course):

```
<script src="/app/directives/monitor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Finally, I was naively intending to call it like:

```
<monitor-button></monitor-button>
```

**Edit**

It is not working, I am not seeing any element in the page.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: All look good, did you get any console error?

Comment: sorry: It is not working, I am not seeing any element in the page.

Comment: did you add `ng-app` directive to bootstrap you angular app?

Comment: One thing I notice is that `var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope, MonitorService) { .. }` should be `var controller = ['$scope', 'MonitorService', function ($scope, MonitorService) { .. }`. When explicitly passing names for injections (which is good practice) you need to remember all the names, and in correct order. Your service finds injections implicitly (kind of). Here the names passed as parameters are assumed to match the name of what you intent to inject, which is not neccesarry in the former.

Comment: @MarkoCen, no, I am not, for it to be independent, is that another way of bootstrap?

Comment: @ThiagoMelo use `angular.bootstrap(document, ['monitorApp']);` at the end of monitor script

Comment: @MarkoCen it worked!!! thanks! would you write an answer for it? so I could mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For independent Angular application, call [angular.bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) to bootstrap your app on page,

```
//monitor.js
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('monitorApp', []);

    //define your app...

    //bootstrap your app...
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['monitorApp']);

})()
```